# Is there any way to use fullHD monitor with macbook (NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB)

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, screen, gpu

I'm trying to use fullHD monitor with my Macbook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010).

Processor:  2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo,
Memory:  4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3,
Graphics:  NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB,
Software:  OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
Monitor: AOC I2353FH

But after something about 20 minutes screen becomes blue and I must to hard reset laptop. Is there any way to work on the big screen or my laptop is too weak for these purposes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you told us everything but what kind of monitor is it, or did I miss that?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I has AOC I2353FH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problem.

The problem seems to first exhibit itself during graphics-intensive tasks like playing games or high-definition video, or running the CPU hot. The display ends up distorting, or going entirely blank, and while reboots make the problems go away for a short period of time, they almost always return later. After the graphical glitches start, things get worse, with many users reporting inevitable gray and blue screens of death.
It’s a bad situation, and frankly, the issue seems obvious: It’s a **heating issue**, to which Macs have always been susceptible. It seems, however, that early-2011 MacBook Pros are particularly prone to this issue. Unfortunately, there’s not much that can be done about it. The only way to fix the issue right now is to swap the logic board on your machine, which is an extremely expensive upgrade.

Read more at http://www.cultofmac.com/262861/early-2011-macbook-pros-dropping-like-flies-heat-issues-blame/#b87oXSQzsCWrqbRy.99

Answer (score 0):

2560 x 1600 is more than "fullHD" or whatever marketing terms they use these days (or those days).  1080p - is often called "fullHD" and is 1920 x 1080 resolution.

QuadHD is quad (4x) 720p or 2560 x 1440 resolution.
The old high def resolution is 2560 x 1600 - this is the resolution of old professional or similar monitors -such as Apple's old 30" cinema display.
2560 x 1600 (or there abouts) requires dual link DVI.  Most high end video cards had at least one of these ports.  HDMI and Display Port should also be able to support these resolution and possibly higher - depending.

4K (also known as UltraHD) is much higher resolution at about 8mega pixels - or around 3820 x 2160 (though full 4K is a bit higher).  Many systems only push 4K at 30Hz - though 60Hz is much more common now, your mileage may vary - void where prohibted!

5K is higher still at around 14 megapixels but takes a lot of computational/gpu to run well ...

Comment: Old? Apple's current model 27" Thunderbolt Display is 2560 x 1600 also.